# Regex - If string contains - or , everything to left else entire string

Tags: regex, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

Help! I've been thrashing on this longer than I care to say. I have a string that may or may not contain a hyphen or a comma. If it does, I want everything to the left of the first occurrence of the hyphen or comma. If it does not, I want the entire string.

`(.*?)[\,\-]`

This is giving me the first part of the puzzle, but this returns a null for the "otherwise give me the entire string" part:

`(?=(.*?)[\,\-]|.*)`

Where am I missing the boat???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/^[^,-]+/
```

i.e. in JavaScript

```
"one two three".match(/^[^,-]+/); //["one two three"]
"one, two three".match(/^[^,-]+/); //["one"];
```

[EDIT, in response to OP's comment about new requirement]

To match only if the letter 'm' is found somewhere in the string:

```
"one two m th,ree".match(/^(?=[\s\S]*m)[^,-]+/); //["one two m th"]
"one two th,ree".match(/^(?=[\s\S]*m)[^,-]+/); //null
```

Comment: This gave me nothing. Unfortunately, this is going thru a 3rd party software, so I don't know what language it's "reallY" being passed to.

Comment: OK, well the REGEX logic is sound - I can't comment on your particular technological set-up as you didn't mention it in your post, hence my example was in JS.

Comment: Ugh, now I have another twist, I only want to do the match on , or - IF the string also has the letter m somewhere within it.

Comment: Thank you again. I love what RegEx can DO, but the syntax of it just baffles me.

Comment: REGEX baffles a lot of people, but it's pure logic and very satisfying - even, perhaps, therapeutic - to do. Well worth learning, as it transfer easily across different languages.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it this way, but its returning a match but no contents
because the `.*` is inside an assertion AND uncaptured.

Usually assertions don't captur anything, but they can match.
In order to capture inside the assertion you have to include capture parenths.

Also, the same applies to assertions within assertions.

So, for a single capture group `$1` you would have to do something like

```
 # ^(?=(.*?(?=[,-])|.*))

 ^ 
 (?=
      (                      # (1 start)
           .*? 
           (?= [,-] )
        |  .* 
      )                      # (1 end)
 )
```

Comment: This works too, but stackoverflow will only let me mark one answer "correct". :-(

Comment: Ugh, now I have another twist, I only want to do the match on , or - IF the string also has the letter m somewhere within it. @sln I truly do not understand RegEx other than very simple uses, even after going thru tutorials...